# Error ('404 not found' )in getting getSymbols() in quantmod

Tags: r, finance, quantmod, google-finance

I am using `quantmod` to run analysis on financial data.I am trying to fetch data from google finance, but I am getting an error.

Error in download.file and HTTP status '404 Not Found'

```
install.packages('quantmod')
setSymbolLookup(QQQ='yahoo',SPY='google')
getSymbols("NSE:JISLJALEQS",src="google") # from google finance
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is because Google Finance does not provide a historical data download for that instrument. There's nothing `quantmod::getSymbols` can do.

If you look on the [Google Finance historical prices page](https://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NSE:JISLJALEQS), you will see that there is no "Download to spreadsheet" link under the chart on the right.

Comment: so how should I get historical prices?

Comment: @NiranjanGd: Use a data provider that supplies them. If you're desperate to get the Google Finance data, you can always scrape the HTML (but please do not ask that to be added to quantmod).

Comment: ya ok. I shall try that. @Joshua Ulrich